# Asp.net aspx page hitting the page load twice......possibly due to the doctype?

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I have read all the articles regarding img and srcs, buttons with autopostpack.  Pretty much everything on this site I have read.  I continue to have a page that is hitting the page load twice during loading.

One of my co-workers mentioned that it is possibly due to the doc-type.  As I have literally stripped my page down to.

Page Language
Doctype
HTML
Head
Body

And it is still hitting the page load twice, I am viewing this via trace.

Any ideas, I am completely stumped and I can't find anything out on the web regarding this.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="testlink.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestApp.testlink" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


</head>
<body >
    <form id="Form1" style="margin: 0px" runat="server">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using both AutoEventWireUp, and manually hook up your Load event handler?

Comment: @User Post your page markup , looking at the page markup will be better.

Comment: AutoEventWireUp is set to false.

Comment: There it is.  As I said very plain page.

Comment: Willing to bet money you're using `PreviousPage`.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by I'm using PreviousPage?

Comment: can you please show code-behind page_load event code?

Comment: just found the issue that was causing this on page_load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out.

Here is the issue.

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, Me.Load
```

Two loads present in the code behind.

Supposedly, this occurred in our system due to upgrades to vs2010......

Comment: Just a small note - doctype has NOTHING to do with issues like this. Never. Doctype only tells the browser what type is the document. +1 that you found an answer yourself and wasn't only waiting for others to resolve this for you.